# SQL Server 2000 constraint involving column on different table

Tags: sql-server, database, constraints

I would like a constraint on a SQL Server 2000 table column that is sort of a combination of a foreign key and a check constraint.  The value of my column must exist in the other table, but I am only concerned with values in the other table where one of its columns equal a specified value.  The simplified tables are:

```
import_table:
part_number  varchar(30)
quantity     int

inventory_master:
part_number  varchar(30)
type         char(1)
```

So I want to ensure the `part_number` exists in `inventory_master`, but only if the type is 'C'.  Is this possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger to emulate that behaviour.

Check value existence when an insert is about to occur.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a trigger on INSERT and UPDATE statements which would ensure the integrity

CREATE TRIGGER syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx